# is "thank you for always remember" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

there's a girl who always text me happy birthday, and I want to make a caption on my ig story thanking her for remembering my birthday, but I don't want to mention my birthday, can I only say "thank you for always remember" or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: "Thank you for remember**ing**."

Comment: "Thank you for ___" requires a noun, and *remember* is not a noun.  You need a noun form of the word there.

Answer (score 2):

You could say thank you for always remembering, which would be grammatically correct.